# Azure Static website authentication to ASP.NET web API

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage

I am new to Azure. I have static website that i will be deploying in AZURE Blob, this website will call ASP.NET web API hosted in Azure (APP service).

Static website will be having one publicly accessible form (Anonymous access) and this form will save data into Azure SQL through ASP.NET web API(Anonymous).

how can i restrict that my web API can be called only from  my static website?

Comment: Ultimately you cannot verify the calling app since it runs on the user's device and you also have no authentication so you cannot verify the user. Probably the most you can do is setup CORS on the API so cross-origin requests will only be accepted from your hosting URL. It doesn't prevent someone from calling your API e.g. using CURL, but it's better than nothing. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to restrict your web api to be accessed only from your static website, you would need to implement CORS(Enable Cross-Origin Request) so that your web api will only allow access from your static web page's url.

[Follow this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api), this should help you to follow and implement it.

I would highly recommend you also implement JWT Token authentication to secure your web api.